# How to iterate through pages while web scraping when URL doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to obtain a list of Branch and ATMs (only) along with their address.

I am trying to scrape:

```
url="https://www.ocbcnisp.com/en/hubungi-kami/lokasi-kami"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui    
import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support    
import expected_conditions as EC    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
driver.get(URL)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()

import re    
import pandas as pd

Branch_list=[]    
Address_list=[]

for i in soup.find_all('div',class_="ocbc-card ocbc-card--location"):
    Branch=soup.find_all('p',class_="ocbc-card__title")
    Address=soup.find_all('p',class_="ocbc-card__desc")
    
for j in Branch:
    j = re.sub(r'<(.*?)>', '', str(j))
    j = j.strip()
    Branch_list.append(j)

for k in Address:
    k = re.sub(r'<(.*?)>', '', str(k))
    k = k.strip()
    Address_list.append(k)

OCBC=pd.DataFrame()    
OCBC['Branch_Name']=Branch_list    
OCBC['Address']=Address_list
```

This gives me the required information on first page, but I want to do it for all the pages. Can someone suggest?

Comment: If you use Selenium then just click Next button to scrape data on next page. Also I see no reason to use regex and BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach using python - **[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io)** simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the API URL which is created using, headers, payload and a dynamic parameter in caps then do POST request.
2. Payload is dynamic you can pass any valid value in the params and the data will be created for you every time you want to fetch something from the site.(!Important do not change value of Page_No parameter).
3. After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
4. Finally it will iterate all over the list of addresses fetched in each iteration or page for ex:- Address, Name, Telephone no., Fax, City etc, you can modify these attributes as per your need.

   ```
   def scrape_atm_data():

   PAGE_NO = 1
   url = "https://www.ocbcnisp.com/api/sitecore/ContactUs/GetMapsList" #API URL

   headers = {
       'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'cookie': 'ocbc#lang=en; ASP.NET_SessionId=xb3nal2u21pyh0rnlujvfo2p; sxa_site=OCBC; ROUTEID=.2; nlbi_1130533=goYxXNJYEBKzKde7Zh+2XAAAAADozEuZQihZvBGZfxa+GjRf; visid_incap_1130533=1d1GBKkkQPKgTx+24RCCe6CPql8AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAChaTReUWlHSyevgodnjCRO; incap_ses_1185_1130533=hofQMZCe9WmvOiUTXvdxEKGPql8AAAAAvac5PaS0noMc+UXHbHc1DA==; SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=e0aa2fcca70c4d999a32fc1f74d09fc8|True; incap_ses_707_1130533=OcSGOGJw3joFLj7x/8TPCVuWql8AAAAAlY3z7ZcDzd/Kba5s5UgLPQ==',       
       }#header and type !Important to add both headers

   while True:
       print('Creating new payload data for page no : ' + str(PAGE_NO))
       payload = 'currPage=' + str(PAGE_NO) + '&query=&dsLocationResult=%7B76EE6530-2A27-46A7-8B32-52E3DAE19DC3%7D&itemId=%7BC59FD793-38C1-444C-9612-1E3A3019BED3%7D'

       response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers,verify=False)
       result = json.loads(response.text) #Parse result using JSON loads
       print('Created new payload now going to fetch data...')

       if len(result) == 0:
           break
       else:
           extracted_data = result['listItem']
           for data in extracted_data:
               print('-' * 100)
               print('Fetching data for -> ' , data['name'])
               print('Name : ', data['name'])
               print('Address : ', data['alamat'])
               print('City : ',data['city'])
               print('fax : ', data['fax'])
               print('Operating Hours : ',data['operation_hour'])
               print('Telephone Number : ',data['telp'])
               print('Location Type : ',data['type_location'])
               print('-' * 100)
           PAGE_NO += 1 #increment page number after each iteration to scrape more data
   scrape_atm_data()
   ```

[image: Output]

Comment: The api url = "https://www.ocbcnisp.com/api/sitecore/ContactUs/GetMapsList" throws an error in my case.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /api/sitecore/ContactUs/GetMapsList

Comment: I'm able to execute same code at my end. Adding screenshot of result

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it throws a JSON Decode Error. Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Comment: No..It gives me a <Response [403]> when I try to see how the response looks like. Probably why it throws a JSON decode error when I try parsing results to JSON loads. Also, I tried opening the api url in my browser, there also the resource can't be found.

Comment: Just now i got the reason why it is giving 403 error

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the url is inaccessible to me and you are able to access it and execute the code?